# How to update React Formik fields based on another field's input?

Tags: reactjs, onchange, formik

Description: I have a Formik form in my React application that has several input fields, including "candet", "valuni", "totdet", and "numite". I want to update the values of "totdet" and "numite" based on the input values of "candet" and "valuni". Specifically, I want to automate the calculation of the values of "totdet" and "numite" based on the values entered in the other input fields.

Currently, I have set up the form using the useState hook and the Formik library. The code for the input fields looks like this:

> Update the values x "numite,totdet" using the inputs form y "candet,valuni"

> Automating the values with just the inputs showed.

Code:

```
const [detfventas, setDetfventas] = useState({        
    candet: "",
    valuni: "",
    totdet: "",
    numite: "",
  });     
<Formik
    ...
    onSubmit={(values, actions) => {                             
              setProductosVentas([...productosVentas, values]);
>            
{({ handleChange, handleSubmit, values}) => (
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>                 
                <input                      
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  type="number"
                  name="candet"
                  placeholder="candet"
                  required
                  value={values.candet}
                />
                <input                      
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  type="number"
                  name="totdet"
                  required
                  placeholder="totdet"
                  value={values.totdet}
                />                   
            </Form>
          )}
</Formik>
```

Update the values x "numite,totdet" using the inputs form y "candet,valuni"

Can someone provide guidance on how to automate the calculation of the "totdet" and "numite" fields based on the values of "candet" and "valuni"? I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answerd

> here added

```
<Formik
      onSubmit={async (values, actions) => {
            values.numite=values.candet;
            values.totdet=values.candet*values.valuni;
            setProductosVentas([...productosVentas, values]);
            }
>
```

> just this

```
values.numite=values.candet;
values.totdet=values.candet*values.valuni;
```